# Capture Service Principal's Name instead of it's ID in TSQL, Azure Database

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-data-factory, service-principal

I am capturing user names in an Azure Database table column using:

```
ALTER TABLE [***] ADD  DEFAULT original_login() FOR [ChangedBy]
```

The problem is that when using Service Principal used by Azure Data Factory i am catching it's ID instead of Name.
Anyone knows how to catch it's name instead?

So I record: `r2s1as1d6-9317-4226-ah89-8...` instead of it's name from `CREATE USER [User Name] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;`

Would appreciate help here

Best!

Comment: `SESSION_USER`, `SUSER_SNAME` ?

Comment: thanks

SESSION_USER worked out but now for my AD user it brings dbo instead of my name.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, this can not achieve with using Service Principal. You can change to use SQL authentication.